# Is there a way to access the original tweets from reply tweets?

Tags: twitterapi-python

I am currently working on a project using the twitter api and I have a dataset of reply tweets containing a certain word. Is there a way to access the original i.e. main tweets from these reply tweets?

Comment: Please give more details about your dataset

Comment: With filter: replies operator, I pulled reply tweets containing a specific word from twitter (e.g. the word "developer"). I want to analyze those tweets by reaching the original tweets from these reply tweets. Is something like this possible ?

Comment: Ok, but what else do you have about each tweet? I'm not sure if you have only the textual content of each tweet

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide an example from your dataset

Comment: For each tweet I have information such as id, textual content, created_at, user screen name, user location, user followers count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, serenayyildiz

You could find the original tweet from one of its replies using [tweepy library](http://www.tweepy.org/):

```py
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(key, secret)
auth.set_access_token(token, token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

with open('tweets.csv','w') as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1)

    for reply_id in list_of_replies:
        reply_tweet = api.get_status(id=reply_id)
        original_tweet_id = reply_tweet.in_reply_to_status_id
        original_tweet = api.get_status(original_tweet_id )
        row = original_tweet.text
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Here are the list of attributes in the Status object, returned when you call `api.get_status`:

- created_at : The time the status was posted.
- id : The ID of the status.
- id_str : The ID of the status as a string.
- text : The text of the status.
- entities : The parsed entities of the status such as hashtags, URLs etc.
- source : The source of the status.
- source_url : The URL of the source of the status.
- in_reply_to_status_id : The ID of the status being replied to.
- in_reply_to_status_id_str : The ID of the status being replied to in as a string.
- in_reply_to_user_id : The ID of the user being replied to.
- in_reply_to_user_id_str : The ID of the user being replied to as a string.
- in_reply_to_screen_name : The screen name of the user being replied to
- user : The User object of the poster of the status.
- geo : The geo object of the status.
- coordinates : The coordinates of the status.
- place : The place of the status.
- contributors : The contributors of the status.
- is_quote_status : Indicates whether the status is a quoted status or not.
- retweet_count : The number of retweets of the status.
- favorite_count : The number of likes of the status.
- favorited : Indicates whether the status has been favourited by the authenticated user or not.
- retweeted : Indicates whether the status has been retweeted by the authenticated user or not.
- possibly_sensitive : Indicates whether the status is sensitive or not.
- lang : The language of the status.

Comment: thank you it worked :)
only the last line will have original_tweet.text instead of tweet.text

Comment: So, do I have the opportunity to access all the original tweets at the same time and save them in a csv file?

Comment: Yes, I edited the code to meet your criteria. Please upvote and accept answer if my solution is helpful